# Spark reading CSV file ClassCastException

Tags: apache-spark

I start Spark 1.6.1 like this:

```
./pyspark --master local[4] --packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.10:1.0.3
```

I can load a CSV file without any errors like this:

```
df = sqlContext.read.format('com.databricks.spark.csv').options(header='true', inferschema='true').load('/home/SparkTest.csv')
```

but when I try to see the data like this:

```
df.head()
```

I get errors like this:

```
16/04/07 10:41:49 ERROR CsvRelation$: Exception while parsing line: 5,2012-01-01,53,Lucky Charms. java.lang.ClassCastException
16/04/07 10:41:49 ERROR CsvRelation$: Exception while parsing line: 6,2012-02-01,14,Cap'n Crunch. java.lang.ClassCastException
```

Comment: Can you try removing schema inference ?

Comment: What is the content of `SparkTest.csv` file?

Comment: I've removed the schema inference option, but the error remains the same.  The csv file lines which look like this: DFLR200,2009-11-02,1000,R100 (ie string, date, number, string).

Answer (score 0):

I was using an older version of the CSV library.
The errors went away when I changed to this argument when I start spark:

```
--packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.11:1.4.0
```